# EF6 + NPGSQL - App.Config Settings - Provider with invariant name 'Npqsql' is either not registered etc. etc

Tags: entity-framework-6, npgsql

Visual Studio 2015 / .NET Framework 4.5

EntityFramework v6.1.3

EntityFramework6.Npgsql v3.1.0

Npgsql 3.2.2

I have inherited a project which contains and EDMX EF6 model which I cannot open in Visual Studio (although the code runs OK) possibly (??) because I am getting the following error: -

> "Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' is
>   either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
>   could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details."

The relevant app.config settings look like this: -

```
<entityFramework>
   <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.2.0" newVersion="3.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

The Schema line from the EDMX looks like this :-

```
<Schema Namespace="MyAppMOdel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Npgsql" ProviderManifestToken="4.0" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
```

I am a bit wary of the ProviderManifestToken="4.0" setting since this project was previously using SQL Server Compact 4. What would be the correct value here?

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone had made some changes by hand:-(

After a lot of faffing (was having trouble with Data Connections & the EDM wizard https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1445) I could see that the ProviderManifestToken should have been "9.6.2"; with that change made my EDMX I am now able to open it withing Visual Studio 2015.

The line in the EDMX file now looks like

```
<Schema Namespace="MyAppModel.Store" Provider="Npgsql" ProviderManifestToken="9.6.2" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
```